# Alias and syntax error

Tags: shell, quoting, alias

The following terminal command will print the output of any other command in a slow fashion.

```
<any command> | awk '{system("sleep .2");print}'
```

I often like to use this and I want to create an alias in ~/.bashrc. However I'm not able to bind it. Any combination of nested apostrophes gives me syntax errors. I'm wondering why this is happening.

Last try was:

```
alias slowprint="| awk '{system("sleep .2");print}'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a function instead:

```
function slowprint { awk '{system("sleep .2");print}'; }
```

Then you can do:

```
seq 1 1000 | slowprint
```

Aliases are not expanded unless they are the first word of the command.

Comment: Perfect. Did not know about functions. Thanks!